# Fixing setup.py after changing a package's directory's name

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I wanted to use `/src` as my project directory instead of its name `/newsite`. I keep getting a ModuleNotFoundError despite having set `package_dir={'':'src'}, packages=find_packages('src')` in setup.py's setup call.

Here is my directory structure:

```
/app
- venv
- src
- - /templates
- - __init__.py
- - newsite.egg-info
- setup.py
- /views
- - __init__.py
- - home.py
```

Here is my setup.py's setup function:

```
setup(name='newsite',
      version='0.0',
      description='newsite',
      classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Framework :: Pylons",
        "Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP",
        "Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: WSGI :: Application",
        ],
      author='',
      author_email='',
      url='',
      keywords='web pyramid pylons',
      package_dir={'':'src'},
      packages=find_packages('src'),
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False,
      install_requires=requires,
      tests_require=requires,
      test_suite="newsite",
      entry_points = """\
      [paste.app_factory]
      main = newsite:main
      """,
      paster_plugins=['pyramid'],
      )
```

And here is the traceback when starting my pyramid webapp with `pserve development.ini --reload`:

```
pyramid_app_1  | Starting monitor for PID 10.
pyramid_app_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
pyramid_app_1  |   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hupper/ipc.py", line 315, in spawn_main
pyramid_app_1  |     func(**kwargs)
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hupper/worker.py", line 267, in worker_main
pyramid_app_1  |     func(*spec_args, **spec_kwargs)
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 32, in main
pyramid_app_1  |     return command.run()
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 253, in run
pyramid_app_1  |     app = loader.get_wsgi_app(app_name, config_vars)
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plaster_pastedeploy/__init__.py", line 131, in get_wsgi_app
pyramid_app_1  |     global_conf=defaults)
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 253, in loadapp
pyramid_app_1  |     return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 277, in loadobj
pyramid_app_1  |     global_conf=global_conf)
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 302, in loadcontext
pyramid_app_1  |     global_conf=global_conf)
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 326, in _loadconfig
pyramid_app_1  |     return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 455, in get_context
pyramid_app_1  |     global_additions=global_additions)
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 564, in _pipeline_app_context
pyramid_app_1  |     APP, pipeline[-1], global_conf)
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 459, in get_context
pyramid_app_1  |     section)
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 481, in _context_from_use
pyramid_app_1  |     object_type, name=use, global_conf=global_conf)
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 412, in get_context
pyramid_app_1  |     global_conf=global_conf)
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 302, in loadcontext
pyramid_app_1  |     global_conf=global_conf)
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 334, in _loadegg
pyramid_app_1  |     return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 625, in get_context
pyramid_app_1  |     object_type, name=name)
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 651, in find_egg_entry_point
pyramid_app_1  |     possible.append((entry.load(), protocol, entry.name))
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2411, in load
pyramid_app_1  |     return self.resolve()
pyramid_app_1  |   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2417, in resolve
pyramid_app_1  |     module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
pyramid_app_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'newsite'
pyramid_app_1  | Server with PID 10 exited with code 1.
pyramid_app_1  | Waiting for changes before reloading.
```

I read what I found online but it seems I'm supposedly doing it correctly.

Comment: Delete the `newsite.egg-info` dir, run `python setup.py egg_info` to recreate the metadata.

Comment: @hoefling I'm creating the .egg within a Dockerfile so it gets destroyed the next time I build, no? Here's the Dockerfile: paste.ee/p/X4aW0

Comment: I see - then the issue is the wrong project structure. You have `src` being a package, so `find_packages('src')` will be empty (does `python -c "import setuptools; print(setuptools.find_packages('src'))"` return anything in the list?). If you want to map `src` to `newsite` when installing (this is what I assume from your entrypoint def), use `package_dir={'newsite': 'src'}` and `packages=find_packages()`. Or make a new package `src/newsite`, move the relevant modules one level deeper and remove `src/__init__.py`.

Comment: @hoefling unfortunately `package_dir={'newsite': 'src'}` didn't work. https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages made me feel like `package_dir={'newsite': 'src'}` would look into `src/newsite/__init__.py`, which may be the cause. I want to avoid moving everything one level deeper, and would like to stick with my directory structure.

Comment: Hmm, I guess my error is in wrong packages collected (I can't test the code out, unfortunately) - `package_dir={'newsite': 'src'}` and `packages=['newsite']` should be it. `package_dir` is the direct mapping of target packages to source locations, so it should be correct that way.

Comment: @hoefling also, `python -c "import setuptools; print(setuptools.find_packages('src'))"` returns `['views']`, while `setuptools.find_packages()` finds `['src', 'src.views']`, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your directory structure is completely wrong. Under `src/` there must be `newsite/` directory containing your Python files:

```
/app
- venv
- src
- - newsite
- - - templates
- - - views
- - - - __init__.py
- - - - home.py
- setup.py
```

Your `setup.py` should work now.

Comment: Why can't I do this without explicitly naming a directory the name of the project?

Comment: Because `find_packages('src')` will not find proper packages.